# CRC: Locate Erroneous Byte

Tags: embedded, crc, redundancy, error-correction, error-detection

Assume a multi-byte block of data is processed twice by some CRC,
once unchanged and once with a single faulty byte. Can the faulty byte
be located solely based on the two codes? Note that does not imply that
the exact nature of the error has to be identified only its location, neither is the byte error restricted to a single bit-flip which can be corrected by any CRC.

Comment: There's not enough information. The number of bits in the CRC, the cyclic period of the CRC polynomial and the number of bytes in the block of data are not mentioned. I assume that "solely based on the two codes" means "solely based on the two CRCs", the one for good data, and the one for bad data. If the answer to the question is yes, does the answer need to include the process of how to determine the location of the faulty byte?

Comment: It is meant in a general sense. Do there exist CRC constructions of any size that offer this property? No need of coming up with a process. For some applications it might be interesting to simply locate the faults without being able to correct them

Comment: You can tell if the single bit error is in the payload part or the checksum (FCS) part, by calculating the checksum for the payload and comparing it with the received checksum. If they are the same, the error is in the payload part, otherwise if they are different, the error is in the checksum part.

Comment: If you have the correct CRC, by definition you know what the original data was, so you can simply compare that.  But if you know a priori what the data will be, there is no need to transmit it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: the CRC for good data and the CRC for data with one bad byte. The two given CRCs are assumed to be good, so there is no error within the CRCs themselves. Xor the good data CRC with the bad data CRC. Consider this as xoring the good data + good CRC with the bad data + bad CRC, the result is data that is all zeroes except for the one bad byte, and a corresponding CRC. The xor also cancels out any initial CRC value or post complementing of the CRC value.

In order to be able detect the location of the bad byte, the CRC needs to be unique for every possible combination of byte location and byte value.

I found that CRC32C polynomial 0x1edc6f41 produces unique CRCs for 1 to 190235 bytes of data. It fails at 190236 bytes of data, as an all zero buffer except for bfr[0] = 0xfb or bfr[190235] = 0x32 both produce the same (non-unique) CRC = 0x364b1c30 .

Example code to determine location given a good crc and a bad crc (one bad byte):

```
static uint32_t crcrtbl[256];

void genrtbl(void)
{
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t b;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            b = crc&1;
            crc >>= 1;
            crc ^= (0 - b) & (0x11edc6f41>>1);
        }
        crcrtbl[c] = crc;
    }
}

size_t crc32r(uint32_t crc, size_t size)
{
    while(size--){
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcrtbl[crc & 0xff];
        if(0 == (crc & 0xffffff))
            break;
    }
    return(size);
}
// ...
genrtbl();  // generate table
// given good_crc and bad_crc, return location
location = crc32r(good_crc ^ bad_crc, size);
```

code to generate crc

```
uint32_t crctbl[256];

void gentbl(void)
{
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t b;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c<<24;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            b = crc>>31;
            crc <<= 1;
            crc ^= (0 - b) & 0x1edc6f41;   // 32 bit crc
        }
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
}

uint32_t crc32(uint32_t crc32, uint8_t * bfr, size_t size)
{
uint32_t crc = crc32;
    while(size--)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ crctbl[(crc >> 24)^*bfr++];
    return(crc);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I guess locating more than one faulty byte is a non-trivial extension?

Comment: @qantik - a single burst error can be detected by reverse cycling the CRC until you get a lot of zero bits, which is what the example code does. This won't work for multiple bad bytes or multiple bad bursts or even multiple bad bits. For multiple bad bits, it's a trial an error process, start with all zeros and try 2 bad bits in every possible combination of locations to see if it matches the CRC, then 3 bits,  then 4 bits, ... .

Comment: @qantik - To handle multiple locations, generally error correcting codes like BCH code (for bits), or RS codes (for bytes or other fixed number of bit elements), are used.

Comment: @qantik- I forgot to mention that I did a brute force check of all 190235 x 255 possible combinations to verify the code shown above works.